# Active Reports WebViewer in IE 11: No report specified

Tags: vb.net, activereports, internet-explorer-11

I have an ActiveReports WebViewer into a User Control and working well in all browsers, except on IE11, where I get the massage: "No report specified".

Is there anyone who know which can be the reason?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following meta tag;

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
```